# Evitar a abertura de mais de uma da mesma JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que utiliza `JInternalFrame` dentro de um `JDesktop`. Quando aperto o botão, essa `JInternalFrame` é instanciada e a janela é aberta, porém, se eu apertar o botão novamente, ele vai abrindo várias janelas iguais. Qual a melhor forma de identificar essa `JinternalFrame` aberta para que quando o botão for apertado, ela não abra outra igual?

Tentei utilizar `isvisible()` porém não obtive resultados.

O evento que chama o JInternalFrame é esse:

```
private void jButton13MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    Fimplantar n = new Fimplantar();
    jDesktopPane1.add(n);
    n.setPosicao();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guarde um seu `JInternalFrame` como um campo da classe que contém esse evento e verifique se ele contém algo antes de criar um exemplar do frame.
Algo assim:

```
public class MeuJDesktop extends JDesktop {

    FImplantar meuJInternalFrame;
    // .....

    private void jButton13MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

        if (meuJInternalFrame != null) {
            this.meuJInternalFrame = new Fimplantar();
            jDesktopPane1.add(this.meuJInternalFrame);
            this.meuJInternalFrame.setPosicao();
        }

    }

    // .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com o código abaixo.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

            if(frameUm == null){
                frameUm = new InternalFrameUm();
                frameUm.setVisible(true);
                desktopPane.add(frameUm);
            }
            else if(!frameUm.isVisible()){
                frameUm.setVisible(true);
                desktopPane.add(frameUm);
            }
        }
```